# Field isn't sent to server

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring

In the page below, the fields from form are sent to server through a jquery script which handles the event submit.

**HTML**

```
    <c:url value="/permissao/cadastra.htm" var="cadastraGrupo"/>
    <form class="form" role="form" action="${cadastraGrupo}" method="post">
        <p> <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" autofocus> </p>

        <table class="bordered">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="permissoes" size="10" multiple="multiple">
                </select>
            </td>

        <td>
            <p> <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" id="for_left"> << </button> </p>
            <p> <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" id="for_right"> >> </button> </p>
        </td>

            <td>
                <select name="permissoes" id="selecao" size="10" multiple="multiple">
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <p> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button> </p>
     </form>

  <div id="yes" class="alert alert-success" style="display: none;">
    <strong>Pronto!</strong> Permiss&atilde;o cadastrado com sucesso.
  </div>

  <div id="not" class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;">
    <strong>Erro!</strong> N&atilde;o foi possivel cadastrar a permiss&atilde;o.
  </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).on('submit', '.form', function (event) {
    // Stop form from submitting normally
    console.log("start of submission");
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get some values from elements on the page:
    var $form = $( this ),
    url = $form.attr( "action" );

    // Send the data using post
    var posting = $.post( url, $(this).serialize() );

    // Put the results in a div
    posting.done(function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#"+data).css("display", "block");

        if($("#pergunta").is("visible"))
            $("#pergunta").css("display", "none");

        $(".form").each (function(){
            this.reset();
        });
    });
});
```

When I check, via browser developer tool, what is sent to server, I see only the field 'nome' is display, but nothing of 'permissoes'. What is wrong here?

PS.: In the server-side, this method from my service class handles the parameters received from client. The variable 'permissoes' is staying with null value.

```
public boolean cadastra(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String nome_grupo = request.getParameter("nome");
    String[] permissoes = request.getParameterValues("permissoes[]");

    if(nome_grupo == null || permissoes == null) {
        System.out.println("nome_grupo = "+nome_grupo);
        System.out.println("permissoes = "+permissoes);
        return false;
    }

    GrupoPermissao grupo = new GrupoPermissao();
    grupo.setNome(nome_grupo);

    List<Permissao> lista = new ArrayList<Permissao>();
    for(int i=0; i<permissoes.length; i++)
        lista.add(permissao.findById(Integer.valueOf(permissoes[i]).intValue()));
    grupo.setPermissao(lista);

    return grupo_permissao.persist(grupo);
}
```

**UPDATE**

HTML output: this is what the browser gets after the jquery script add the options dinamaclly:

```
<select id="permissoes" size="10" multiple="multiple">
                    <option value="1">cadastra_produto</option><option value="2">altera_produto</option><option value="3">remove_produto</option><option value="4">cadastra_categoria</option><option value="5">altera_categoria</option><option value="6">remove_categoria</option><option value="7">cadastra_promocao</option><option value="8">altera_promocao</option><option value="9">remove_promocao</option><option value="10">cadastra_destaque</option><option value="11">altera_destaque</option><option value="12">remove_destaque</option><option value="13">cadastra_usuario</option><option value="14">altera_usuario</option><option value="15">remove_usuario</option><option value="16">cadastra_configuracao</option><option value="17">altera_configuracao</option><option value="18">remove_configuracao</option><option value="19">cadastra_preferencia</option><option value="20">altera_preferencia</option><option value="21">remove_preferencia</option><option value="22">cadastra_perfil</option><option value="23">altera_perfil</option><option value="24">remove_perfil</option><option value="25">cadastra_materia_prima</option><option value="26">altera_materia_prima</option><option value="27">remove_materia_prima</option><option value="28">cadastra_quantidade_materia_prima</option><option value="29">altera_quantidade_materia_prima</option><option value="30">remove_quantidade_materia_prima</option><option value="31">cadastra_descricao_materia_prima</option><option value="32">altera_descricao_materia_prima</option><option value="33">remove_descricao_materia_prima</option><option value="34">cadastra_fornecedor</option><option value="35">altera_fornecedor</option><option value="36">remove_fornecedor</option><option value="37">cadastra_endereco</option><option value="38">altera_endereco</option><option value="39">remove_endereco</option><option value="40">cadastra_contato</option><option value="41">altera_contato</option><option value="42">remove_contato</option><option value="43">cadastra_unidade</option><option value="44">altera_unidade</option><option value="45">remove_unidade</option><option value="46">cadastra_permissao</option><option value="47">altera_permissao</option><option value="48">remove_permissao</option><option value="49">dashboard</option></select>
```

**UPDATE 2**

What's happening it's that I need select manually all elements from second select to they be sent to server. I don't want that because the user already select them from first select and transfer all to the second one. Then, I am looking for a way to select all items from select before submit the form (using jquery code).

Comment: You have 2 `<select>`s in the form with the same name, which isn't good, but none of them has a single option so neither of them will be submitted thus you'll not have a `permissoes` post variable on server side..

Comment: Can you show us the actual HTML output so that we can see the options that are added dynamically to the drop-down list? And as @MarcellFülöp said, you need to rename one of your select lists.

Comment: the full html code is this: https://github.com/klebermo/lojavirtual/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view/jsp/privado/permissao/cadastra.jsp. Only one of the selects have name, and it's the one I want send to server.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined select box but it does not have any options

```
<select name="permissoes" id="selecao" size="10" multiple="multiple">
</select>
```

Moreover for debugging purpose,  you should inspect the value in alert/firebug  for firefox/some other debugger in javascript before sending it to server

Comment: the options are added dinamically, through jquery code using a json file. see here: https://github.com/klebermo/lojavirtual/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view/jsp/privado/permissao/cadastra.jsp

Comment: Please stop using `alert()` for troubleshooting. Use `console.log()` instead.